# Low Time-of-Flight Lambert Solver Trajectory Errors

Tags: trajectory, interplanetary, time-of-flight

I have a Lambert solver that is used to calculate the required delta-V for interplanetary transfer trajectories, but I recently ran into a problem. It works well for "long" time-of-flight trajectories (for example, a 250 day trajectory from Earth to Mars), but if I try a "short" time-of-flight trajectory (for example, a 45 day trajectory from Earth to Mars), the solver seems to break, by having its calculations not converge. I realise that a 45 day TOF is rather unrealistic, but I usually perform a mid-course correction halfway through a trajectory, so if I have a fast 90 day TOF, then I'll perform a MCC 45 days into the flight (which is when the solver breaks).

The following is the Lambert solver which uses a Universal Variables formulation (coded in the Mathematica language) and a simple iterative bisection solver to calculate the required delta-V given a require time-of-flight:

EDIT: I've since fixed the code and the Lambert solver below seems to work quite well:

```
G = 6.672*10^-11; (*Gravitational Constant*)
m[0] = 1.988544*10^30; (*Mass of Sun*)
TOF = (45) (86400); (*Time-of-flight in seconds*)
R[1] = {-1.1751563715176448`*^11, 8.982523733108002`*^10} (*Heliocentric position of Earth*)
R[2] = {-5.256112524631399`*^10, -2.1604439066188406`*^11} (*Heliocentric position of Mars*)
R1 = Sqrt[R[1].R[1]]
R2 = Sqrt[R[2].R[2]]
\[CapitalDelta]\[Nu] = ArcCos[R[1].R[2]/(R1 R2)] (*Change in true anomaly, in radians*)
A = Sqrt[R1 R2 (1 + Cos[\[CapitalDelta]\[Nu] ])];

iterationCount = 0;
z = 0;
zhi = 4 \[Pi]^2;
zlow = -4 \[Pi];
c[z_] := If[z > 0, (1 - Cos[Sqrt[z]])/z, 
  If[z < 0, (1 - Cosh[Sqrt[-z]])/z, 1/2]]
S[z_] := If[z > 0, (Sqrt[z] - Sin[Sqrt[z]])/Sqrt[z^3], 
  If[z < 0, (Sinh[Sqrt[-z]] - Sqrt[-z])/Sqrt[(-z)^3], 1/6]]
Y[z_] := R1 + R2 - (A (1 - S[z] z))/Sqrt[c[z]];
X[z_] := Sqrt[Y[z]/c[z]];
t[z_] := (X[z]^3 S[z] + A Sqrt[Y[z]])/Sqrt[G m[0]];

t[z] = t[z]; (*Initial value for t[z]*)

(*Iterative Bisection Solver*)
While[Norm[t[z] - \[CapitalDelta]t] > 1*10^-6 && iterationCount < 100,
 c[z_] := 
  If[z > 0, (1 - Cos[Sqrt[z]])/z, 
   If[z < 0, (1 - Cosh[Sqrt[-z]])/z, 1/2]];
 S[z_] := 
  If[z > 0, (Sqrt[z] - Sin[Sqrt[z]])/Sqrt[z^3], 
   If[z < 0, (Sinh[Sqrt[-z]] - Sqrt[-z])/Sqrt[(-z)^3], 1/6]];
 Y[z_] := R1 + R2 + (A (S[z] z - 1))/Sqrt[c[z]];
 (*Making sure Y>0*)
 While[A > 0 && Y[z] < 0,
  zlow = zlow + 0.01;
  z = (zhi + zlow)/2;
  c[z_] := 
   If[z > 0, (1 - Cos[Sqrt[z]])/z, 
    If[z < 0, (1 - Cosh[Sqrt[-z]])/z, 1/2]];
  S[z_] := 
   If[z > 0, (Sqrt[z] - Sin[Sqrt[z]])/Sqrt[z^3], 
    If[z < 0, (Sinh[Sqrt[-z]] - Sqrt[-z])/Sqrt[(-z)^3], 1/6]];
  Y[z_] := R1 + R2 + (A (S[z] z - 1))/Sqrt[c[z]];
  ];
 X[z_] := Sqrt[Y[z]/c[z]];
 t[z_] := (X[z]^3 S[z] + A Sqrt[Y[z]])/Sqrt[G m[0]];
 If[t[z] <= \[CapitalDelta]t, zlow = z, zhi = z];
 z = (zhi + zlow)/
  2; (*Re-calculating z using bisection root finding method*)
 Print[Norm[t[z] - \[CapitalDelta]t]];
 iterationCount++;];

    f = 1 - Y[z]/R1;
    g = A Sqrt[Y[z]/(G m[0])];
    gdot = 1 - Y[z]/R2;
    vLambert[1] = (R[2] - f R[1])/g; (*Required velocity at start of trajectory*)
    vLambert[2] = (gdot R[2] - R[1])/g; (*Velocity at target arrival*)
```

As can be seen, there are checks in place to make sure Y always stays positive, so I'm not too sure what the problem could be. Searching the internet for any academic articles or book chapters has unfortunately not given me a solution to this problem either. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have experience with Mathematica, but at least the line
`While[A > 0 && Y[z] < 0, zlow = zlow + 1];` seems to be strange. Increasing the lower bound for `z` without updating your criteria will result in an endless loop once it is started! `A` is a constant of the specific problem and `Y` depends on `z`, not on `zlow`.

Comment: Looking closer I see that that was indeed where my problem lay and it has since been fixed. Thanks very much!

Comment: indigoblue,  would you kindly post your newly corrected code here?